# Putting If() inside an array()

Tags: php

Is it possible to put if statement inside an array like this

```
array(1 => 1, 2 => 2 if(!empty(3)){echo ", 3 => 3";});
```

instead of going

```
if(!empty(3)){
    array (1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3);
}
else {
    array (1 =>1, 2 => 2);
}
```

Comment: Did you try it and see? Also, there are other options besides the one you showed for doing this. In PHP there's usually more than one way to do it.

Comment: some variable is intended here `!empty(3)`

Comment: As an (abhorrent) one-liner: `[1 => 1, 2 => 2] + (!empty(3) ? [3 => 3] : [])`…

Comment: @deceze Why would this be abhorrent?

Comment: Bad readability. Explicit and easily readable should always trump terseness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the value after you created the array

```
$array = [1 => 1, 2 => 2];
if (...) {
    $array[3] = 3;
}
```

if you don't need the key, you could also just write

```
$array[] = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [ 1 => 1, 2 => 2  ];
    if ( !empty(3) ) { 
        $array[3] = 3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional operator for value like below

```
$array = array(
    '1' => '1',
    '2' => '2',
    '3' => $cond ? '3' : ''
);
```

if you need to add condition in key you can do below way

```
if ($cond) {
    $array[3] = 3;
}
```

you can also use `array union operator` or `array_merge`:

```
array('1' => '1') + ($cond ? array('3' => '3') : array())
array_merge(array('1' => '1'), $cond ? array('3' => '3') : array())
```

now you have to decide what is better for you.